# Mouse can click but won't move

Tags: mouse, 16.10

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10. My cursor won't move but I can click anywhere in the desktop. Can you help me to solve my problem ? Thank you.

```
$ xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer
2: "Virtual core pointer"       [Xpointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
9: "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" [XExtensionPointer]
```

My Comp. Spec.

i5-6600K

Gigabyte Z170-HD3

Team Xtreem Dark DDR4 3000MHz 2x4GB

Galax GTX 1070 EXOC

Comment: Is [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/966283/28930) related?